# Leetcode 1838: Frequency of the Most Frequent Element java solution

Tags: java, arrays

Assignment Question:

> The frequency of an element is the number of times it occurs in an array.
> You are given an integer array `nums` and an integer `k`. In one operation, you can choose an index of `nums` and increment the element at that index by 1.
> Return the maximum possible frequency of an element after performing at most `k` operations.
>
> Example 1:
> Input: nums = [1,2,4], k = 5
> Output: 3
> Explanation: Increment the first element three times and the second element two times to make nums = [4,4,4].
> 4 has a frequency of 3.
>
> Example 2:
> Input: nums = [1,4,8,13], k = 5
> Output: 2
> Explanation: There are multiple optimal solutions:
>
> - Increment the first element three times to make nums = [4,4,8,13]. 4 has a frequency of 2.
> - Increment the second element four times to make nums = [1,8,8,13]. 8 has a frequency of 2.
> - Increment the third element five times to make nums = [1,4,13,13]. 13 has a frequency of 2.
>
> Example 3:
> Input: nums = [3,9,6], k = 2
> Output: 1

I have tried to solve with the below code and it fails for the test case

Test case:

```
int[] nums = {9930,9923,9983,9997,9934,9952,9945,9914,9985,9982,9970,9932,9985,9902,9975,9990,9922,9990,9994,9937,9996,9964,9943,9963,9911,9925,9935,9945,9933,9916,9930,9938,10000,9916,9911,9959,9957,9907,9913,9916,9993,9930,9975,9924,9988,9923,9910,9925,9977,9981,9927,9930,9927,9925,9923,9904,9928,9928,9986,9903,9985,9954,9938,9911,9952,9974,9926,9920,9972,9983,9973,9917,9995,9973,9977,9947,9936,9975,9954,9932,9964,9972,9935,9946,9966};
int k = 3056 ;
```

Result: 72 and

Expected: 73

Code below:

```
class Solution {
public int maxFrequency(int[] nums, int k) {
    int maxFreq = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        int k_remaining = k;
        int curr_freq = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
            if (i == j) continue; // ignore if index matches

            if (nums[i] < nums[j]) continue; // ignore if the ith indexed number is less than the jth index number.

            if (k_remaining < 1) break;
            System.out.println("k_remaining: " + k_remaining + ", nums[i]: " + nums[i] + ", nums[j]: " + nums[j]);
            int diff = nums[i] - nums[j];
            // System.out.printf("i: %d, j: %d, nums[i]: %d, nums[j]: %d and diff: %d k_remiaining: %d\n", i, j, nums[i]m nums[j], diff, k_remaining);
            System.out.println("diff: " + diff);
            if (diff <= k_remaining) {
                ++curr_freq;
                k_remaining = k_remaining - diff;
            }
        }
        if (curr_freq > maxFreq) maxFreq = curr_freq;
    }
    return maxFreq;
}
```

I thought might be due to the boudary conditions and trace it. I tried to count by tabulating in the spreadsheet and there also I can count only 72. If someone tried this earlier and share their findings, it would be great.

Below is the attached spreadsheet

```
1   9930    53  3003
2   9923    60  2943
3   9983    0   2943
4   9934    49  2894
5   9952    31  2863
6   9945    38  2825
7   9914    69  2756
8   9982    1   2755
9   9970    13  2742
10  9932    51  2691
11  9902    81  2610
12  9975    8   2602
13  9922    61  2541
14  9937    46  2495
15  9964    19  2476
16  9943    40  2436
17  9963    20  2416
18  9911    72  2344
19  9925    58  2286
20  9935    48  2238
21  9945    38  2200
22  9933    50  2150
23  9916    67  2083
24  9930    53  2030
25  9938    45  1985
26  9916    67  1918
27  9911    72  1846
28  9959    24  1822
29  9957    26  1796
30  9907    76  1720
31  9913    70  1650
32  9916    67  1583
33  9930    53  1530
34  9975    8   1522
35  9924    59  1463
36  9923    60  1403
37  9910    73  1330
38  9925    58  1272
39  9977    6   1266
40  9981    2   1264
41  9927    56  1208
42  9930    53  1155
43  9927    56  1099
44  9925    58  1041
45  9923    60  981
46  9904    79  902
47  9928    55  847
48  9928    55  792
49  9903    80  712
50  9954    29  683
51  9938    45  638
52  9911    72  566
53  9952    31  535
54  9974    9   526
55  9926    57  469
56  9920    63  406
57  9972    11  395
58  9983    0   395
59  9973    10  385
60  9917    66  319
61  9973    10  309
62  9977    6   303
63  9947    36  267
64  9936    47  220
65  9975    8   212
66  9954    29  183
67  9932    51  132
68  9964    19  113
69  9972    11  102
70  9935    48  54
71  9946    37  17
72  9966    17  0
```

Comment: Please add the assignment to your question. You should not expect other SO users to go to an external website that you didn't even link and read an assignment there to solve it for you. Also that website could vanish, change its links, etc.

Comment: added the original question to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are all sorts of problems with your algorithm.

For example, given:

`[10, 20, 20, 30, 30]` and k = 20, the right move is to forget about the `a[0]` and instead use your 20 available increments to get both `a[1]` and `a[2]` up to 30, for a max freq of 4. Your algorithm doesn't 'select', it always just goes. It'll spend 20 on getting 10 to 30, it won't get the answer right for this scenario. Your solution gets this wrong (the next problem described in the following paragraph *also* goes wrong in this example case; your solution returns 2 when the correct answer is 4).

A second place where your code fails is the `break;`. Once you run out of `k` to spend you just break. This fails, if there are further elements in the array that need 0 increments to get to the right number. You can trivially trigger this, too; try input [10,10,10] with `k=0`. Your app returns '1'. The correct answer is 3.

There are no easy fixes to your solution to address these issues.  The second problem (the `break;`) is easily addressed, but you need a pretty much entirely different algorithm to tackle the first problem. You have to toss most of it it and start anew. I'm not sure there's much to learn when I add a working solution to this answer, that's not really what SO is for and would seem pointless (surely the point of you doing this exercise is to learn something, you don't learn nearly as much when you just get provided the answer).

I make no guarantees that these 2 issues cover all problems. Merely that each one individually is sufficient to explain why your solution is wrong. There might be more.

### So how do you approach these issues?

Usually by first 'exploring the space'. What is *interesting* about the problem? Generally this involves writing out examples yourself. These questions tend to ship with a small set of examples, and some will tell you when your solution fails, which test it fails on, but, [A] not all such exercise things do that (some just say: "Nope, wrong!" without telling you which test case(s) it failed on), [B] the spirit of these things is not that you submit some garbage just to get some more involved test cases out, and [C] often the test cases that fails are humongous and make it difficult to tell what, exactly, is wrong.

You fell into the [C] trap here: You think you're almost there because seemingly only this rather large test case fails, and only by 1 degree. But, turns out, your solution is unsalvagable, and you couldn't tell in what way based on the failed test case that was provided.

Hence, unless you are experienced enough, always start out by hand cooking up some test cases. That's exactly what I did here, and came up with `[10, 20, 20, 30, 30] k = 10` and `[10, 10] k=0`.

You do this not *just* to have test cases. Also to get a general understanding of the problem.

Where this gets orders of magnitude more complicated is that these programming puzzles are generally designed to be challenging in an 'algorithmic complexity' way. They don't *just* want you to code a program that calculates the solution. **They want you to program the fastest possible program that does it**. For most of the more challenging coding exercise I've ever seen (and I've seen hundreds if not thousands, from many sources, it's a bit of a hobby), the problem really isn't 'write code that solves the problem'. It's 'figure out what the fastest algorithm is'.

That's where it turns into an olympic-level sport. It takes *years* of experience and study of complex fundamental informatics concepts (such as big-O notation, and a good grasp of the NP-complete problem space). It's a two-phase thing: You have to understand the fundamentals (NP-completeness, big-O notation) and then need the experience to quickly recognize the ways an algorithm translates into big-O/NP-completeness so that you can shoot them down (anything slower than O(n^2) is usually too slow - if you're fast at recognizing an algorithm you're forming to tackle the problem is just not going to end up being fast enough, you know to abandon that line of thought and think of something else). Some of the tools in the toolbelt are algorithms that are known to be 'fast enough', such as dynamic programming, so you can simplify problems into 'oh, that can be done with dynamic programming'. Basically you build up a library of exercises and the approach to solve them, and then the exercise is to restate a problem in terms of known exercises which you already know an approach for that is fast enough. And the knowledge to know how combining parts of standard solutions affects runtime performance.

So how do you get *there*? Oof. Be good at math, university degrees, read a lot, lots of exercise. But, baby steps: You can't get to 'think about a good algorithm' if you don't even know the lay of the land - and given that you hadn't, apparently, even considered the `[10, 20, 20, 30, 30] k = 10` case, you didn't have the lay of the land. So, work on that first. For the next exercise (or even for this one), spend a lot more time on writing out examples. Don't rely on the ones that the exercise provides (they tend to serve to *clarify*, not to give you the lay of the land), and don't rely on failed tests (they tend to be too complex to serve as tools to understand the lay of the land, and many such puzzler exercises do not provide them at all).

### A few hints, perhaps?

- Instead of going through the array from start to finish, which runs into the problem of spending too much to increment low numbers, you want to increment in order. You want to spend your `k` on the *closest* lower number first (in the `[10,20,20,30,30]` case, the 20s are closer than the 10s, so you want to spend your limited `k` on the 20s first).
- The order of the numbers in your input is **irrelevant**. Swap numbers around the array and the answer does not change. Hence, modifying their order doesn't change the answer. Is there a different order you can put them in that markedly simplifies the exercise?

Comment: @user85421 Yes, it should be. Typo fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understood that using that break definitely breaks the code. Also understood that the approach, start to finish does not work. Thanks again.